# Upgrading Oh My Zsh gives me 'not a git repository' error

Tags: git, oh-my-zsh

Since I upgrade my OSX to El Capitan when I want to update Oh My Zsh `upgrade_oh_my_zsh` I got the following error:

```
Upgrading Oh My Zsh
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
There was an error updating. Try again later?
```

I never used git before, searching this fatal error on the internet they advice to do `git init` in the `/.oh-my-zsh` folder. After running this command a new fatal error occur when I try to run `upgrade_oh_my_zsh` again.

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I don't know if it has anything to do with with it but when I open the terminal (iTerm2) I also got this notification:

```
/Users/peter/.zshrc:1: command not found: Path
```

Anyone has experience with this or knows a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Looks like your git repo was removed from oh-my-zsh? You can re-add the remote and update to the latest version of Zsh by running:

```
cd ~/.oh-my-zsh
git init # you've already done this step, so you can skip
git remote add origin https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh.git
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```

After that, restart your terminal instance and you should be good to go.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this worked! Just when i did the last step i had to remove the `--hard` first and after that do it again with `--hard`

Comment: didn't work. I still get the error when i open a new terminal window

Comment: For me I had to `merge` after the `fetch` and that seemed to work.

Comment: My issue was Xcode update. Even the error message was same, I had to launch Xcode and accept some terms. Better to check Xcode first if you had same error.

Comment: @travis Can you please update the instructions and use `https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh` instead?

Answer (score 19):

I just encountered that message. In my case (on a Mac) it just so happens that I just installed Xcode, and that git stopped working until I accepted its terms and conditions. Just in case...

Comment: The same happened to me. When I ran `omz update`, I was instructed to run `sudo xcodebuild -license`, as I had recently installed Xcode. Running the command fixed the issue.

Comment: I already had xcode but I updated my macOS and it reset it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53089103/4654175

Answer (score 16):

The above solution didn't work for me.
The problem in my case was that I have an alias

`alias gpucb="git pull origin $(git branch --show-current)"`

As soon as I commented it the error was gone.
I need a fix for this. 
Also, the weird part is that the error is encountered only in the second `git` command.

Comment: Your problem is that the command `$(git branch --show-current)` is executed at the evaluation of the alias. To solve this, you can escape `$` using `\\`

Comment: Or use single quotes to wrap the alias, that seems to work too.

Answer (score 8):

For me, the root cause of the error was the upgrade to macOS Ventura.  Doing `xcode-select --install` and restarting the terminal fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

When I had this issue, I started by seeing what happened to my git

```
$git --version
```

Then it prompts to accept the new agreement on XCODE. So I ran

```
$sudo xcodebuild -license
```

After that, it will install the updates, then open XCODE.

Then all will be fine.

Comment: in my case, this was the solution. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case macOS Ventura 13.x.
Download and installed [Command Line Tools for Xcode 14.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Command%20Line%20Tools%20for%20Xcode%2014)
it's solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

By trying the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33487142/12763686), I got this error:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

However, running this (and restarting the terminal) helped me:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52522566/12763686)

Answer (score 0):

rm -rf "$ZSH"

sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same error message and it was because of Xcode update. I had to start Xcode and accept some license & feature changes. Afterwards, the message has gone.

I believe the message is result of multiple processes. Not only git problems but also for Xcode.

It's better to check Xcode if you face with this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is due Xcode upgrade.
Open Xcode.app in your MAC, accept new terms and conditions and then it will install some upgrades and error will disappear from oh-my-zsh.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to do a system update. The issue was resolved after the update.