# Git is not working after macOS update ("xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools")

Tags: xcode, git, macos, command-line, terminal

I updated to the latest OS, and/or restarted my computer (this happens on every major update, but this time all I did was restart my computer on 2022-09-13).

This morning I navigated to my work's codebase in the command line on my [MacBook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro), typed in "git status" in the repository and received an error:

(In 9/2022, this error was much different, but I didn't capture it)

> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

Git will not work!

How do I fix Git, and the command-line tools?

Comment: This is more of a git problem than a macOS problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a

Comment: to be honest, this problem is something APPLE should take care of. They create it, they should fix it !!!!! Asking everyone to run that command everytime this happens isn't an Good/Correct option. Not to mention you need to download that big chunk for git only.

Comment: I didn’t run into it on my update to Big Sur. Only had this problem the year when I originally wrote this Q&A. I’ve just been updating it every year to include the latest changes.

Comment: If you don't have Xcode, only installing Xcode command line tools will solve the problem. https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=command%20line%20tools

Comment: alianjum0, thanks for that.  I just went down a huge rat hole being unable to install XCode from the AppStore (long story).  Being able to install just the CLI saved the day!

Comment: We should get paid by apple for debugging their code!

Comment: It's a failure to completely update ALL their software during a major version update. I have not run into this since i initially made the question and answer! So it works on some level i suppose!

Comment: @dustbuster No. It's not a problem with git. It's a macOS problem. You get the same error from other commands like make. The solution is what I thought it was but I checked here anyway as I wanted to be sure - too much going on to worry about possible fixes.

Comment: Another OS update and yet 3 years later, issue still exist.

Comment: I updated to Monterey and faced the same issue. Apple really needs to look into this issue.

Comment: I never had this issue before and I've been using macOS since about the last 3 years. However I just updated it to Monterrey and it broke git.

Comment: "This is more of a git problem ..." how so?  git is merely a command line tool.  I've used git on other platforms for decades and have never encountered this issue until working on a Mac.  What the hell does git have to do with XCode?

Comment: I wrote that 3 years ago matey! lol But yea. it's totally a macOs problem. I did not think this would be a relevant for 3 years!

Comment: Is there some issue/ticket in an Apple help system that we can upvote to try to get more attention on this?

Comment: No need to download Xcode. I am using MacOS Monterey version 12.x. I have downloaded "Command Line Tools for Xcode 13.3 beta". Restarted terminal and command line is working along with github clone/pull/push issues. It worked like charm.

Comment: Again the same problem with Ventura! Come on, Apple!

Comment: I'm also having the same problem with Ventura @Upendra. If this happens with every macOS update (it breaks Git), it would be nice if someone could at least write a nice blog post about this...

Comment: I had the problem with Ventura as well. Solution for me was to launch the Xcode app once.

Comment: Every year around fall i got a huge surge of rep from this Q and A. you'd think developers would be the one group of folks they want to make happy. I think some of my counter answers are right. Switch to Brew, forget about this problem forever! I do like the simulate phone feature of xocde. I think that's worth having, but other than that, i do not need x-code!

Comment: apple somehow seems to be discouraging developers to use a mac without xcode ! this is outright monopilistic behaviour. The only thing apple is notorious for.

Comment: All hail the apple and its PITA git! lol

Comment: Thank you Creator for Stack Overflow! I got this issue when I just upgraded to Sonoma... installed v15.1 and worked like a charm.

Comment: Agreed! What a great community this is! CasaCoding!

Answer (score 5050, accepted):

The problem is that Xcode Command-line Tools needs to be updated due to a MacOs update.

- Did not run into this on Sonoma.

  - Maybe Apple fixed the process?
- Updated for Ventura

After opening the terminal after restarting, I tried to go to my code, and do a `git status`, and I got an error and prompt for command line software agreement:

So press space until you get to the `[agree, print, cancel]` option, so careful hit space to scroll down to the end, if you blow past It you have to run a command to get it back. Use `sudo xcodebuild -license` to get to it again.

Just be careful on scrolling down and enter `agree` and press return and it will launch into an update.

[image: Xcode software license]

Then I tried to use git after the install, and it prompted me to install Xcode tools again.

I followed my own advice from previous years (see below), and went to [https://developer.apple.com/download/all](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) and downloaded
"Command Line Tools for Xcode 14" (You have to log in with your Apple ID and enter MFA code, so have all the devices you need for that handy. Then select "Command Line Tools for Xcode 14", or if you want to get into the alphas or betas, that's up to you. But stable releases are probably the best choice for software developers.

[image: developer download page selection for "Command Line Tools for Xcode 14"]

**You have to either download the tools from CLI or the developer page and before you can use git, you need to reboot!!! Or you will get stuck in a loop of prompt & downloading**

Rebooting will break the loop and complete the installation of your CLI tools *including* git so that you can get back to work

Solutions for previous years, these may or may not be valid these days as the downloads page has changed significantly:

PREVIOUS YEARS SOLUTIONS, probably #2 is most helpful.

*** **Solution #1**:

Go back to your terminal and enter:

```
xcode-select --install
```

You'll then receive the following output:

```
xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools
```

You will then be prompted in a window to update Xcode Command Line tools. (which could take a while)

Open a new terminal window and your development tools should be returned.

**Addition:** With any major or semi-major update you'll need to update the command line tools in order to get them functioning properly again. Check Xcode with any update. This goes beyond Mojave...

**After that restart your terminal**

Alternatively, **IF that fails,** and it might.... you'll get a pop-up box saying "Software not found on server", proceed to solution 2.

*** **Solution #2**: (Preferred method)

If you hit `xcode-select --install` and it doesn't find the software, log into Apple Developer, and install it via webpage.

Log in or sign up here:

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Look for: **"Command Line Tools for Xcode 14.x"** in the list of downloads
Then click the dmg and download. (See previous image above) either way, you will probably wind up at an apple downloads webpage.

Comment: This fixed the issue I had with Microsoft Visual Studio Code which was complaining about Git not being installed when I first launched it after upgrading to Mojave. I thought the issue was VS Code, but it was the issue in this SO question. Restarting VS Code after installing the Xcode Command-line Tools solved the issue.

Comment: I wish the Xcode update was part of the OS update. Something like this happens every time I upgrade. Annoying.

Comment: It's happened to me on every update. I guess the majority of Mac users don't have Xcode installed! Otherwise apple probably would update it at the same time. .

Comment: Definitely annoying though. A simple check for Xcode installation and then an update during the OS update would be pretty simple to add. It's always something with these OS updates from Apple. You'd think they'd have figured it out by now.

Comment: In case you installed GIT and this is still not working you might need to add an alias: `sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Comment: I'd already visited the App Store, and it claimed to find no updates.  Why can't it recognize that Xcode needs to be updated?

Comment: For anyone using Git in PHPStorm; you need to restart PHPStorm after running `xcode-select --install`. Then it'll work.

Comment: Same SVN issue got fixed by this method as well.

Comment: When I go to install (after agreeing to T's & C's) I get "Can't install the software because it is not currently available from th Software Update server." Has anyone else gotten this?

Comment: I did not need to restart my terminal btw.

Comment: Nothing is working for me. I am using Sourcetree on same repository. it shows the username and email correctly.

Comment: For me running `open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` after the `xcode-select --install` command worked, following [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave)

Comment: This solution works for me for Mac Catalina update also. Superb!!!

Comment: I updated the text to just say "MacOs update" I am very happy it works for Catalina! Figured it would!

Comment: just wanted to add that you need to restart the computer, 
also a good `brew doctor` may also help find any issues

Comment: I am using android studio on Mac, recently updated OS to Catalina. After updating OS, stop connecting to Version Control (subversion). But thanks to @dustbuster, installing xCode solve the my problem.

Comment: But why ? Why do we need to do this ? my question is to Apple falks

Comment: Should I do the same with zsh too ?

Comment: You will not have to do anything to zsh Tilak. The issue is git. Not zsh.

Comment: After the update , you need to make sure to restart all the applications and IDE that depend or have connection with git like all IntelliJ IDEs ,sublime with git , source tree etc to make it run properly,

Comment: If you have Xcode installed, you **do not need the separate command line tools install**. Just make sure you run `xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` or `xcode-select --reset` so Terminal will use the command line tools inside Xcode instead of the ones installed by the "command line tools" standalone installer. From then on, the App Store will auto-update Xcode and your tools will stay current.

Comment: _July 2020 Update_: This answer worked for me on Mac OS Mojave (after upgrading from El Captain). Takes a while to install though. (Just doing `xcode-select --reset` as mentioned in other answers did not work for me)

Comment: The way apple manages the xcode downloads has changed. I actually ran into this myself AGAIN when i upgraded this year! So i updated the answer not too long ago.

Comment: For PyCharm also need to do like PHPStorm as suggested by @DaanvandenBergh . That is need to restart PyCharm after running `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Upgraded to macOS Big Sur and here it is again.

Comment: I have updated this answer every year! Check out solution #2, that's probably the most relevant. There's a surge this time every year!

Comment: I had to download `Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_12.3_beta.dmg` for MacOS 11.1 Big Sur. Then it worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear! I have not updated yet. is that the name of the download file now?

Comment: thanks a lot! I immediately went for solution 2 once I read that solution 1 might very well fail haha.

Comment: Most Excellent! I actually didn't run into it this time around when I updated to Big Sur.

Comment: How could Git is not part of OSX? If not, then make it never part of OSX? what's the benefits of bundling a developer tool in the operation system which is not responsible for updating it?

Comment: Awesome! Solution #1 works for me. Thanks :)  It's so annoying to do this after every minor update. Techies at Apple Listen O Listen !!

Comment: You should not have to do it after every update, that is annoying!!

Comment: I update Xcode to Version 12.5 (12E262), which is the latest one. And I get this same error. Does it means I need to do `xcode-select --install` each time manually?

Comment: `xcode-select --install` + terminal restart fixed broken git after Catalina -> Big Sure update!

Comment: Solution 1 worked for me running macOS 11.5.1. Thank you :D

Comment: on the update to monterey, it worked like a charm (xcode-select --install).
Thank you so much!!

Comment: I updated from macOS Big Sur -> macOS Monterey, Nov 01, 2021.  

Same problem with git:  

`xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`. 

   
 This installation solved the problem:   

`xcode-select --install`

THANK YOU!!!

Comment: I cannot believe this problem has not been solved in November 2021. Apple WTH?

Comment: I updated recently to MacOS Monterey , and this update of xcode tools was able to fix this exact same issue. Thank you.

Comment: No need to download Xcode. I am using MacOS Monterey version 12.x. I have downloaded "Command Line Tools for Xcode 13.3 beta". Restarted terminal and command line is working along with github clone/pull/push issues. It worked like charm.

Comment: I never understood why XCode is required for git or why it interferes with my git installation in the first place. I tried to uninstall Xcode completely to avoid this situation, but that did not work out well

Comment: For iOS Monterey, I went with 13.3.1.  And git started working again.

Comment: Works perfect with macOS Catalina

Comment: My first dev job was in .Net. I remember thinking Visual Studio was huge and invasive. It's got nothing on Xcode.

Comment: Yep I feel the same way! I learned how to code in college using Visual Studio. Now if I accidentally double click a file that's registered to open with Xcode I go right for the force quit! Do not pass go and no 200 bucks for you!

Comment: I recently upgraded to Monterey 12.5 and I did not need to restart my iterm2 so maybe add a step to check before restarting

Comment: The first option requires 15GB of space to install. any other way?

Comment: Deja vu, wow. Every bigger Mac update I'm back here... 
This should get fixed at some point.

Comment: This worked for me after the macOS Ventura 13.0 update.

Comment: All I had to do was to go to Xcode - Preferences - Locations and select the Command Line Tools from the dropdown that was empty, after updating to macOs Ventura.

Comment: @mvndaai I'm so confused why xcode wouldn't update with a macOS update. Isn't  xcode also produced by apple? https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: You don't have to update Mac to update Xcode, when you update macOS first, like to Montery, you have to update Xcode.

Comment: Wow, I'm stuck without git on my mobile data plan (on a trip).

I don't use any Apple dev tools. This is embarrassing...

Comment: Damien Maybe Install git using brew. Much less downloading! I think how to do that is below somewhere!

Comment: Your link "https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Command%20Line%20Tools" is actually linked to "https://developer.apple.com/download/more/" And your text says download "Command Line Tools" but the screenshot highlight "Additional Tools"

Comment: Image and link updated ^^ stuff changes at developer.apple all the dang time!

Comment: Along with this great answer, I had to follow the advice on this post first, then I was able to run the `xcode-select --install`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939354/tool-xcodebuild-requires-xcode-but-active-developer-directory-library-devel

Comment: This Q & A has gotten me nearly 80K in rep! Thanks to all for the upvotes! I love you all!

Comment: If anyone runs into this on Sonoma, please. add an update. I did not run into any issues this go around. maybe Apple fixed the problem?

Comment: Had this issue still in MacOS Sonoma Version 14.1 (23B74) and got it resolved using the `xcode-select --install` option, thanks!

Comment: Awesome! I did not run into it with Sonoma. Glad it still worked!

Comment: None of the command line inputs worked but going to the website and downloading the latest stable release fixed it right up!!! A'hehee!!!

Answer (score 383):

I got some errors that the software was unavailable from the update server when trying

```
xcode-select --install
```

What fixed it for me was going here https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and downloading `Command Line Tools (macOS 10.14) for Xcode 10` and then installing it manually.

After that, the errors should be gone when you open up a new terminal.

---

**Update for macOS Ventura 13.0.1 (Nov 2022)**

Install [Command Line Tools for Xcode 14.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Command%20Line%20Tools%20for%20Xcode%2014)

Comment: This should be the right answer, tried on 3 machines and  @dustbuster answer doesn't work anymore and it shows "software was unavailable from the update server when trying"

Comment: For me this ends with `software not available at server` but @High6's answer below works. `xcode-select --reset`

Comment: downloading ``Command Line Tools (macOS 10.14) for Xcode 10.1`` from the link. thanks!

Comment: Had xcode installed still there were issues. This worked like a charm... should be the selected answer. Or should be addendum to top answer.

Comment: This also works for macOS 10.15.2. Though I had to select `Command Line Tools for Xcode 11.3`, since Xcode 10.1 wasn't available

Comment: On Mac OS 10.15.6 Catalina, this was the solution that worked for me. (Command Line tools for Xcode 12 if you're on Catalina - skip the mammoth Xcode 12 app download)

Comment: Resolved same issue for me.

Comment: On macOS Ventura 13.0.1, this also resolved for me by installing Xcode from the App Store.

Comment: Your update for macOS Ventura helped me out. It seems, that even restarting is unnecessary.

Comment: Above command itself worked for Vetura as well without restarting

Comment: Even though I was able to `xcode-select --install` for Ventura, I was not able to push anything. Downloading the command line tools pkg installer did work for me.

Answer (score 181):

For me `xcode-select --reset` was the solution on Mojave.

Comment: somehow, "xcode-select --install" ends of software not available at server. But this one works

Comment: This worked for me, I ran this command after installed new Xcode.

Comment: I just upgraded from Mac OS X 10.14 (Mojave) to MacOS 10.15 (Catalina) and faced this problem, this solution worked fine, it was no necessary to run `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: works for me on Catalina as well, but needed to add `sudo`

Comment: `sudo xcode-select --reset` worked for me on a Mojave --> Catalina upgrade of MacOS

Comment: *2020 Update*: Same solution for Catalina OS

Comment: _July 2020 Update_: This did not work on Mac OS Mojave (after upgrading from El Captain). This worked from the accepted answer: `xcode-select --install`. Takes a while to install though

Comment: Does not work for Catalina. `sudo xcode-select --reset` appears to do nothing.

Comment: I needed to run this command after I migrated from old Mojave MBP  to new Catalina MBP and couldn't have git etc running; intellij complained

Comment: This did not work on Monterey.

Comment: Had a same problem and this works :)

Comment: Update 2022: works on Darwin 21.4.0

Comment: Worked for me on Ventura

Answer (score 113):

In addition to dustbuster's answer I needed to set path to the Xcode folder with this command:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Comment: Yep same for me, @dustbuster might be a good idea to merge these answers.

Comment: Ok this one solved this for me. Tried `xcode-select --install` and downloading and installing manually, none of the solutions worked. Note that I waited and upgraded to version 10.14.1.

Comment: If you have Xcode installed, you **do not need the separate command line tools install**. Just make sure you run `xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` or `xcode-select --reset` so Terminal will use the command line tools inside Xcode instead of the ones installed by the "command line tools" standalone installer. From then on, the App Store will auto-update Xcode and your tools will stay current.

Comment: been through so many answers, this is the one that worked for me after the Mojave update, thanks!

Answer (score 95):

updated from Mojave to Big Sur and got the same error :
the command

```
xcode-select --install
```

worked like a charm

Answer (score 65):

After upgrade to Mac `Catalina` I faced the same issue, I had to run couple of commands to get this fixed.

First started with:

`xcode-select --install`

It didn't fix the problem, had to run the following in `sudo`

`sudo xcode-select --reset`

Then, finally got fixed after I switched and set the path explicitly for active developer directory:

`sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

**Note:** In case you have `Xcode` installed, you may need to specify `Xcode` directory in this case, it should be something like this

`xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app`

Comment: If you have Xcode installed, you **do not need the separate command line tools install**. Just make sure you run `xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` or `xcode-select --reset` so Terminal will use the command line tools inside Xcode instead of the ones installed by the "command line tools" standalone installer. From then on, the App Store will auto-update Xcode and your tools will stay current.

Comment: Xcode select did it since I only had the beta version installed!

Comment: Try `sudo xcode-select --reset` first then `--install`

Answer (score 54):

For me what worked is the following:

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Then like in @High6's answer:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

This will reveal a license which I assume is some Xcode license. Scroll to the bottom using <kbd>space</kbd> (or the mouse) then tap `agree`.

This is what worked for me on MacOS Mojave v 10.14.

Comment: your solution worked for me on MacOS 10.13 High Sierra. Thank you.

Comment: If you **have Xcode installed**, this is the correct solution. Terminal will use the command line tools inside Xcode instead of the ones installed by the "command line tools" standalone installer. From then on, the App Store will auto-update Xcode and your tools will stay current.

Comment: This is working for BigSur as well as the Monterey beta branch. Way easier than downloading and installing giant new Xcode releases each time you update.

Comment: This did the trick for me and fixed VSCode not finding Git after I migrated from my old iMac running Catalina to my shiny new Apple Silicon MacBook Pro running Monterey via Migration Assistant.

Answer (score 54):

If you use `xcode` then install it (~12GB)

```
xcode-select --install
```

Otherwise install latest [command line tools](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) (~500MB)

[image: Downloads]

> Update: If struck in install loop

```bash
xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

Comment: I've (re)installed xcode so many times over the past 2 years that it's like "How many times do I have to teach you this lesson, old man?"

Answer (score 53):

- if there are several versions, select one of them from:
  xcode -> Preferences and tap Locations then select, as the followng  image

[image]

Comment: This fixes a couple items, but not all

Comment: I had Xcode 10.3, 11.1 and 11.2 and Xcode wasn't able to figure out which version to use for the Command Line Tools and left the dropdown with empty. Once 11.1 was selected for my purpose, git commands started to work.

Comment: This popup is equivalent to calling `xcode-select --switch` with the path to the Xcode package of whatever version you select here, by the way.

Comment: Good hint thank you , Whatever the way , the important thing is to solve the issue

Comment: This works for me.. Thanks a lot. I was having old and new version of Xcode at different locations.

Comment: downvoted: you must understand the installing xcode is what is the worst option. Why should we be forced to installe 600MB of xcode just to enable the path of an already installed git?

Comment: This is great way, without using `xcode-select --install` I chose only this path by xcode gui.

Answer (score 52):

I've used `xcode-select --install` given in the accepted answer in previous major releases.

I've just upgraded to OS X 10.15 Catalina and run the Software Update tool from preferences again after the OS upgrade completed. The Xcode utilities update was available there, which also sorted the issue using git which had just output 
`xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools)`

Comment: If you have Xcode installed, you **do not need the separate command line tools install**. Just make sure you run `xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` or `xcode-select --reset` so Terminal will use the command line tools inside Xcode instead of the ones installed by the "command line tools" standalone installer. From then on, the App Store will auto-update Xcode and your tools will stay current.

Answer (score 48):

I figured out the Xcode Command Line Tools part from the error message, but after running Xcode and getting the prompt to install the additional tools it did claim to install them, but still I got the same error after opening a new terminal.

So I did the `xcode-select --install` manually and after that it worked for me.

Comment: If you have Xcode installed, you **do not need the separate command line tools install**. Just make sure you run `xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` or `xcode-select --reset` so Terminal will use the command line tools inside Xcode instead of the ones installed by the "command line tools" standalone installer. From then on, the App Store will auto-update Xcode and your tools will stay current.

Answer (score 43):

Mac OS : **Big Sur**

First Priority

```
sudo xcode-select --reset

sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Second Priority

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Best answer for Big Sur

Comment: For big Sur, this first priority is usefull. Thanks for saving lot of time and Data.

Comment: I am using Big Sur (xcode-select --install) helped me.

Comment: Work for me on catalina

Comment: best answer! This issue doesn’t require installation of the tool again

Comment: According to the XCode man pages(Yea they do have documentation!!!)

```
       -r, --reset
              Unsets  any  user-specified  developer  directory,  so  that the
              developer directory will be found via the default search  mecha-
              nism.  This  command must be run with superuser permissions (see
              sudo(8)), and will affect all users on the system.

```

Comment: Thanks - worked for me! Why do MacOS upgrades always break dev tools? Disincentivizes upgrading since this is my dev laptop.

Comment: Thanks - worked for me! Why do MacOS upgrades always break dev tools? Disincentivizes upgrading since this is my dev laptop.

Comment: Getting below error on BigSur

➜  ~ sudo xcodebuild -license
dyld: dyld cache load error: existing shared cache in memory is not compatible
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Reason: image not found
xcrun: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
xcrun: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch

Answer (score 35):

Following worked on M1

```
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.2.1
BuildVersion:   20D74

% xcode-select --install
```

Agree the Terms and Conditions prompt, it will return following message on success.

```
% xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools
```

Answer (score 33):

If you have Xcode downloaded manually (i.e. not from the App Store) or don't have Xcode at all:

1. `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`
2. Go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ to download Command Line Tools (macOS 10.14) for Xcode 10
3. Setup Command Line Tools

If you have Xcode installed from the App Store:

1. `xcode-select --install`

Comment: I want to install Command Line Tools only and Not Xcode. This solution seems to be the best. Minimal install

Comment: Perfect for me since I don't need Xcode but I do need Git :)

Comment: After I installed Catalina and trying the `xcode-select --install` answer I had an error from the UI installer: "xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools". This was the only thing that worked for me since I didn't want to install Xcode. (I used the Command Line Tools for XCode 12.)

Answer (score 30):

Open Terminal:

install XCode developer tools and fix the problem.

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

Reset the path to Xcode if you have several versions:

```
$ xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
$ xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Comment: If you have Xcode installed, you **do not need the separate command line tools install**. Just make sure you run `xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` or `xcode-select --reset` so Terminal will use the command line tools inside Xcode instead of the ones installed by the "command line tools" standalone installer. From then on, the App Store will auto-update Xcode and your tools will stay current.

Comment: Also, it makes no sense to do both calls to `xcode-select --switch` above. The second one overwrites what the first one did. Do the first one and your command line tools will update as part of Xcode.

Answer (score 27):

1. Run this command:

xcode-select --install

2. Hit return for a progress indicator on the Command Line Tools download.
3. After installation of the Command Line Tools has been completed, your Mac should be rebooted. If you’re getting “xcrun error invalid active developer path” while working in Terminal, refresh the application or relaunch it.

Even after following the above-mentioned steps, if you see the error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools). The next step would be to try and install Command Line Tools using a DMG file that can be downloaded directly from the Apple website.

Again, if you are using Homebrew, you need to update it. You don’t need to uninstall and again [install Homebrew on Mac](https://techrechard.com/how-to-install-homebrew-on-mac/).

NOTE: If you are using Homebrew, try updating it after re-installing Command Line tools.

Credits: [Git not working after macOS Update](https://techrechard.com/solved-git-not-working-after-macos-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-library-developer-commandlinetools/)

Answer (score 14):

This just happened to me after upgrading my MacBook Pro to [macOS v13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura). After the upgrade, the Git command line stopped working with showing up this message.

> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path
> (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

Running `brew upgrade` fixed the Git command line.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I've deleted Xcode before because I don't need it anymore.

Comment: I've got an error: `Error: No developer tools installed`

Answer (score 12):

As of September 13, 2022, I had a similar issue after upgrading my [MacBook Pro M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Sixth_generation_(M1)) to [macOS v12.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey) (Monterey), and although I followed some of the answers, my Mac kept prompting me with a dialogue to install Git as a developer tool. Every time that the installation was completed, I was prompted to the same dialogue.

Finally, I had to do a combination of all the answers to make it work:

1. First remove the command line tool:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
   ```
2. Reinstall the `xcode-select`:

   ```
   xcode-select --install
   ```

The above will prompt you with a dialogue to confirm the installation.

3. Set path to the Xcode folder with following:

   ```
   sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
   ```

Answer (score 10):

I observed in the Catalina privacy setting if Xcode not added in Full access disk I will get the same error, Xcode does not run scripts. Add your Xcode the same as in the attached image. After that clean build and run. Hope so it will work.
[image: Security & Privacy]

Answer (score 9):

For me, I didn't have xcode installed (on Mojave OS). I went to the App Store on my mac and downloaded it, then went back to terminal and typed `git` and hit enter, then it worked.

Answer (score 9):

I found that my version of Xcode was too outdated and installing command-line-tools wasn't helping. Here's what I did:

- I completely uninstalled the outdated XCode
- I reinstalled the most recent XCode from the app store
- That was all. Git was restored.

Answer (score 9):

For me, for the [macOS v13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura) user, installing this software helped:

[image]

I wasn't able to run any Xcode install commands, and Git was not working at all.

You can find this package here
https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

Comment: This also worked for me by installing Xcode through the App Store.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me

```
sudo xcode-select --reset 
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

X-code must be installed.

Answer (score 6):

For those using Catalina and Xcode-beta:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 5):

I updated my macOS yesterday，from macOS Mojave（10.14.6）to macOS Catalina（10.15.7），I was executing "git" command in my project. I get same errors。

run：

```sh
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Please don't repeat existing answers

Answer (score 5):

After Updating macOS to ***Monterey*** (12.3) from ***BigSur*** getting such issue

only worked-

> xcode-select --install

Done!

Comment: That is the same with the accepted answer, but with less information!

Answer (score 5):

With previous app development experience, may I say with confidence that the Git version delivered with Apple always create problems. So the sooner you get rid of Apple Git the better, so may I suggest:

```
brew uninstall git
brew update
brew install git

# which git
/usr/local/bin/git
```

Comment: I think you might have the right idea bud. I ran into issues twice. Idk why I need a full development suite just to have git.

Answer (score 4):

For me It happened after Mac OS update to Mojave and git was not functioning in Intellij

Solution:-
Go to Settings, then File | Settings | Version Control | Git and edit Path to Git executable field which is /usr/local/bin/git

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and couldn't use **SVN** after the update,

Just in case if doing  **xcode-select --install** didn't fix the issue,

You might see,

> svn: error: The subversion command line tools are no longer provided by Xcode.

Refer : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_release_notes

Try installing the svn by **brew**

```
brew install svn
```

This should get you going.

Comment: I have been thinking that brew is perhaps a better source for git! So much overhead using apple developer.

Answer (score 3):

**MacOS :Monterey**
**Year: 2022**

**Solution: Upgrade to 12.2.1 or later**

I upgraded to Monetery 12.2 as my Macbook pro got replaced. Ran into same issue as OP:

> `Git is not working after macOS Update (Xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools)`

One would think that by this time Apple would have added xCode & developer tools into OS main build. Turned out they did. I had to upgrade to 12.2.1, which included "**command line tools for xCode**".
I still need to do step upgrade to 12.4 , but I believe we finally have these tools as part of OS build.

Here's screen-shot while attempting to upgrade from 12.2.1 to 12.3.1 (I forgot to take one while upgrading from 12.2 to 12.2.1, but I am pretty sure it had same Addons)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am using [macOS v13 13.3.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura) and an Intel chip [MacBook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro) and ran this code:

`xcode-select --install`

This code worked for me from [iTerm2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITerm2), but I had to run the code twice and go through the installation twice.

It was a good option for me as it avoided installing all of Xcode and just the command line tools.

It took about 5 minutes with the crappy coffee shop Wi-Fi!

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers worked for me. I had a couple of issues. First, I installed the ***latest version*** of **Xcode**, **14.0 beta**. That ***ended up*** **not working** because it was a **version** that is ***not compatible*** with **Monterey**. And my **computer** is ***too old*** to ***install*** **Ventura beta**. So I had to go and find out which version of Xcode actually did work. And that ***ended up being*** **13.4.1**. So I ***installed*** that. I had taken all the right steps beforehand to delete the old version, and then placed the new one, as always, into my **Applications** folder. But for whatever reason, it did not end up there. When I ***checked*** to ***see*** if my install was ***successful***, **errors** were ***thrown*** in **Terminal**. I had also ***previously*** ***updated*** **CLT**, which ***included*** the ***correct version***. However, **Terminal** ***returned*** that I ***needed*** to ***install*** **CLT**. And ***when*** I ***tried***, it told me that it was ***already installed***, but I should ***change*** the **path** of my Xcode or ***install*** **CLT** (which **obviously** was ***not*** a ***real option***). I ***found*** the **solution** in this **article** ***entitled*** [Xcode-select active developer directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17980759/). And I ***ran*** the ***following command*** in **Terminal** which ***fixed*** my **path**:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Hope this helps anyone else who encounters the same issue when trying to update Xcode on macOS Monterey and also can't update to macOS Ventura.

Comment: Identical to many of the existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

For [macOS v13.0.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura).

Update for macOS Ventura 13.0.1 (Nov 2022)

[Install Command Line Tools for Xcode 14.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Command%20Line%20Tools%20for%20Xcode%2014)

It's worked for me.

Comment: Came here after installing Ventura caused this issue. This worked for me too

Comment: You should not just link to solutions. You can provide the link as reference but you should actually explicitly include the solution in your answer on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you created a new Applications folder in an external drive and installed Xcode there:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Volumes/MyExternalStorageName/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 1):

Edge case, but still worth writing down: when migrating from and older Mac with Migration Assistant, you may have selected the option to transfer all your applications from your older Mac. Applications, like Xcode needs to be updated if it was transferred and preserved OR delete from your other user's Applications folder. This is because Xcode has not been set up properly after the first start with the new OS version.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue after updating to [macOS v13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura).

Command: `xcode-select` also does not seem to work. So does `sudo xcodebuild`.

After checking Xcode itself, it installs the command line tools and the said command still fails to work.

[image]

After checking this part, it appears to be blank. I just manually set it to use the available command line from the installed Xcode and everything now works, including Git.

Comment: related stuff. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error so it is probably the order I did things that failed the commands.

Answer (score 1):

#### For [macOS v13.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura)

I updated from [macOS v11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur) to Ventura 13.1 (January 2023). I only installed Xcode on the [App Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_(iOS/iPadOS)), and it worked for me.

[image]

Comment: For me, I go to App store, update Xcode then have to do one more step, which is open Xcode and click to `Agree` with their license then everything is working fine.

Comment: Yes, you have to open XCode so it can install the extra stuff that apparently includes git

Comment: apple is really a data eater

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer for [macOS v13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura)

Update the Xcode from [App Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_(iOS/iPadOS)), and then run:

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

---

#### Explanation

First, updated the Xcode from App Store.

Make sure it is pointing to the correct location. Go to Xcode → *Settings* → *Locations*:

[image]

Then check the path of "active developer director". To check, run:

```
xcode-select -p
```

Output:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

It is pointing to separately installed command line tools, which is incorrect, because we already have Xcode installed. It should point to the *Applications* folder where Xcode is installed. To do that, run:

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Now it must have reset the path. Confirm it by running:

```
xcode-select -p
```

Output:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

---

Just in case the reset doesn't fix the issue. Explicitly set the path:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Mac Sonoma 14.3.1 and I fixed it with

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

hope it works for people that looking for this problem in **Mac Sonoma**

Answer (score -1):

After updating the Mac OS to **Sonoma**, I was facing the same issue. The below command helped me to resolve the issue

```
xcode-select --install
```

After running this command, you will be prompted to install, just click yes and continue with the installation.