# Getting Xcode error when using terminal and git

Tags: xcode, git, macos, macos-mojave

I am getting this error when trying to work with git:

```
Mitchells-MacBook-Pro:/ Mitch$ git
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDocumentation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDocumentation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
git: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
git: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch
```

I am running on MacOS mojave. I have tried to run command:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

which does not seem to do the trick. Any tips would be great.

Comment: Does sudo `xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` work any better?

Comment: @PhillipMills not quite, still getting the same errors after.

Comment: What do you get if you enter `which xcodebuild`?

Comment: The result: `/usr/bin/xcodebuild`

Comment: One more thought....  Do you get a result with `cd /Applications/Xcode.app/; find . -name xcodebuild`?

Comment: I get the result; `./Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182874/discussion-between-sgerbhctim-and-phillip-mills).

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-mojave-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-devel

Answer (score -1):

Try upgrading Xcode via the App Store

Comment: Could someone indicate why they downvoted this suggestion?