# Unable to ssh to github after upgrade to Mojave

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh

I have not had a problem with ssh and github until a recent upgrade to Mojave - I regenerated several ssh keys but I get the same errors. Below is the end of my readout from: ssh -vT git@github.com It authenticates but then hangs and finally returns the broken pipe message.

```
 debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
 debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
 Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.253.112]:22).
 debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
 debug1: Entering interactive session.
 debug1: pledge: network
 debug1: Sending environment.
 debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
 debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_US.UTF-8
 packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.30.253.112 port 22: Broken pipe
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52522565/354577

Comment: Or this: https://superuser.com/a/1373701/54530

Comment: That did it thank you! put it as an answer if you want the credit or I can

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-mojave-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-devel