# Failed building wheel for sha3

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, command-line, pip

My PyCharm console suggested that `ImportError: No module named sha3`
So I've decided to install this module.

However, this error emerged when using the command of `pip install sha3`, the whole process and descriptions are below.

```
Collecting sha3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b3/b4/d23c8e8843226dcf54c6c533a6717d34d50358f74496cfa77e6e8c7e146a/sha3-0.2.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: sha3
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for sha3 ... error
  Complete output from command /Applications/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/fc/_2t60h750rl4svnh50tp3l7h0000gn/T/pip-install-mlrjkbkr/sha3/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/fc/_2t60h750rl4svnh50tp3l7h0000gn/T/pip-wheel-rsy0_asx --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/sha3
  copying sha3/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/sha3
  running build_ext
  building '_sha3' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/src
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/src/64
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Applications/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Applications/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Isrc/ -Isrc/64 -I/Applications/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c sha3.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/sha3.o
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for sha3
  Running setup.py clean for sha3
Failed to build sha3
Installing collected packages: sha3
  Running setup.py install for sha3 ... error
    Complete output from command /Applications/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/fc/_2t60h750rl4svnh50tp3l7h0000gn/T/pip-install-mlrjkbkr/sha3/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/fc/_2t60h750rl4svnh50tp3l7h0000gn/T/pip-record-15ac0elc/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/sha3
    copying sha3/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/sha3
    running build_ext
    building '_sha3' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/src
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/src/64
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Applications/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Applications/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Isrc/ -Isrc/64 -I/Applications/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c sha3.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/sha3.o
    xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Applications/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/fc/_2t60h750rl4svnh50tp3l7h0000gn/T/pip-install-mlrjkbkr/sha3/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/fc/_2t60h750rl4svnh50tp3l7h0000gn/T/pip-record-15ac0elc/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/fc/_2t60h750rl4svnh50tp3l7h0000gn/T/pip-install-mlrjkbkr/sha3/
```

I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: `xcrun` points to XCode. You could try running `xcode-select --install` to enable the developer tools and try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git is not working after macOS Mojave Update (xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-mojave-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-devel)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmacos%5D+error%3A+invalid+active+developer+path+missing+xcrun