# How to solve Issues with installation of 'rlang' package?

Tags: r

I am trying to install Tidyverse but I cannot get the rlang package to download.

I am using R version 3.5.3, and I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling R. Furthermore, I have tried to install Tidyverse as well as the rlang package individually.

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

```
install.packages("rlang", dependencies=TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))
```

With both of these methods, I get the same error message.

```
* installing *source* package ‘rlang’ ...
** package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rlang’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: From the paths in the output I'm guessing this is OSX, unfortunately I don't know much about getting set up to compile packages on Mac.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-mojave-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-devel

Comment: @Tung thankyou that worked!