# cocos studio can't be open I am running it on Mac

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, cocos-studio

I am on macOS Catalina, Version 10.15.
When I am trying to open Cocos Studio it says

> **cocos studio can't be open**
>   [image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming and probably belongs on **Ask Different** Stack Exchange site where it will likely get a better response.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I think it is valid to have a question like this. For example we have such question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-pa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that 32-Bit Apps 'Not Optimized for Your Mac' No Longer Working on macOS Catalina.
According to https://www.macrumors.com/guide/32-bit-mac-apps/
When macOS Mojave was announced, Apple warned that it would be the last version of macOS that would support older 32-bit apps. Apple has been phasing out 32-bit apps for the last 10 years and is now ready to take the final step, even if Mac users may not be ready to lose access to older apps.