# How to use opendiff and git diff and not needing to install the whole Xcode app?

Tags: xcode, git, git-diff, filemerge, opendiff

After upgrading to MacOS Mojave, my `git` and `opendiff` stopped working (my `opendiff` is usually invoked by `git diff`).

I was [able to get `git` working, by using the following two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-pa):

```
xcode-select --install
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

but `opendiff` and `git diff` still doesn't work. It seems one solution is to install the Xcode app, which is huge (said to be taking up 10GB on the hard drive). I checked Spotlight and typed FileMerge, and was able to find it, which should be the same as `opendiff`, and was able to use `ps ax` to find the path `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/FileMerge`.  But then, using `git diff`, I actually used a bash script to invoke

```
#!/bin/sh 
/usr/bin/opendiff "$2" "$5" -merge "$1" | cat
```

(see this [github article about how to set up `git-diff-cmd.sh`](https://gist.github.com/bkeating/329690))

so I changed that second line to:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/FileMerge "$2" "$5" -merge "$1" | cat
```

but it doesn't work.  So FileMerge exists, and it looks like `opendiff` is FileMerge.  Can `git diff` be made to work without needing to install the whole Xcode app?

Answer (score 1):

This may seem like a hack, and in fact it seems like it is using an existing installation of XCode:

I did

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app
find . -iname '*opendiff*'
```

and was able to find

```
./Contents/Developer/usr/bin/opendiff
./Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/mergetools/opendiff
```

The first file is a binary file, and the second one is actually a script, so I changed my bash script `git-diff-cmd.sh` to the following:

```
#!/bin/sh 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/opendiff "$2" "$5" -merge "$1" | cat
```

and `git diff` can successfully invoke `opendiff` to do a visual diff.

Answer (score -1):

> Can git diff be made to work without needing to install the whole XCode app?

Install the whole BBEdit app instead. It’s small and efficient and does a very nice visual diff.

Comment: I remember choosing a visual diff tool before and the Perforce p4 diff was another good one. I saw the screenshot for BBEdit diff in https://eclecticlight.co/2018/04/14/comparing-files-filemerge-opendiff-and-bbedit/ and it seems quite good too