# Issue with installation of pytabix on macbook

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to install pytabix package to run few scripts on python 2.7.18 version. However, I am getting this error message during installation through `pip install pytabix`

Here is the error message:

```
Installing collected packages: pytabix
  Running setup.py install for pytabix ... error

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nn/r79_1jvx02n3l31_9hkk9jsw0000gn/T/pip-install-AGIV85/pytabix/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nn/r79_1jvx02n3l31_9hkk9jsw0000gn/T/pip-install-AGIV85/pytabix/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/nn/r79_1jvx02n3l31_9hkk9jsw0000gn/T/pip-record-_HD_40/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/nn/r79_1jvx02n3l31_9hkk9jsw0000gn/T/pip-install-AGIV85/pytabix/
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/test
    copying test/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/test
    copying test/test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/test
    copying test/example.gtf.gz -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/test
    copying test/example.gtf.gz.tbi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/test
    running build_ext
    building 'tabix' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/src
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_USE_KNETFILE=1 -Isrc -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/bgzf.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/src/bgzf.o
    xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-pa) you could find an answer:

```
xcode-select --install
```

The error says `xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun` so you need to look for this error how to resolve it.

The next command also could be a solution:

```
xcode-select --reset
```

And if that did not helped, try the next:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions helped me resolve the issue and I successfully installed pytabix.