# My macbook is not working with running clion

Tags: c, cmake

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /Users/yeweihao/Desktop/untitled1
- The C compiler identification is unknown
- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - broken
CMake Error at /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  
The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /Users/yeweihao/Desktop/untitled1/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_cbdd4/fast && xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/yeweihao/Desktop/untitled1/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/yeweihao/Desktop/untitled1/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

[Failed to reload]
```

Comment: Have you searched for the error message you got (`error: invalid active developer path`)? Have you checked e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-pa) and its answer which suggests to update XCode?

Comment: I'm going on a limb here, but the path it looks at for xcrun looks uncommon, maybe your "active developer path" should be `/` instead of whatever it is now, so that it looks for xcrun in `/usr/bin` instead

Comment: xcode-select --install it shows about can't download because of network problem?