# xcrun: error: invalid active developer path, problem after zsh update for flutter

Tags: flutter, error-handling, zsh, zshrc, xcrun

I updated my shell to zsh and when I type flutter --version I get this:

```
'''xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools),   
missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Failed to find the latest git commit date: VersionCheckError: Command exited
with code 1: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ad
--date=iso
Standard out: 
Standard error: xcrun: error: invalid active developer path
(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

Returning 1970-01-01 01:00:00.000 instead.
Flutter 0.0.0-unknown • channel unknown • unknown source
Framework • revision  () • 1970-01-01 01:00:00.000
Engine • revision b8752bbfff
Tools • Dart 2.10.2'''
```

WHAT SHOULD I DO? I'm not an expert in these things XD.

Kind regards,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git is not working after macOS Update (xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-pa)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It looks like the Command Line tools path is not set. If you have XCode then to setup the path you need to:

1. Open XCode
2. Open Preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>)
3. Go to Locations tab
4. For “Command Line Tools” select the current version
   [image: screenshot showing preference]

Comment: Still works as of 28 Sept 2022, thanks!

Answer (score 65):

The error messages seem to be about Xcode CLI tools? If so, try these commands to reset it:

```
xcode-select --install
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Ventura complains `error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/'`

Comment: Just the first step xcode-select --install solved the issue for me

Answer (score 3):

Download the latest Command Line Tools for Xcode and install it to solve the problem. Complete installation of Xcode is not required.

[Apple Developer Download link](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=command%20line%20tools)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on macOS Catalina and want to do this via the commandline/terminal, or the above solutions haven't worked, try these steps:

1. Disable `SIP` *(this needs to be done via recovery mode)*
2. Create a `soft simlink` linking your "Developer" directory *(which contains the CommandLineTools directory/instance `brew` is searching for)* by running: `sudo ln -s /path/to/Developer /path/to/Xcode.app/Contents`
3. Run the simlinker built into `brew`, to let `brew` know where the CommandLineTools instance is *(`brew` was written by default to support both instances running in the same directory and has refused to update for logical reasons their docs explain)*, by running: `sudo xcode-select --switch /path/to/new/simlinked/directory/for/CommandLineTools`

Here's an example on my system:

- Xcode was originally located in: `/Applications/Xcode.app`
- Developer directory, containing CommandLineTools was: `/Library/Developer`
- ran: `sudo ln -s /Library/Developer /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/`
- ran: `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/CommandLineTools`
- refreshed shell *(or open a new instance)*, and then ran: `brew doctor`, receiving the message: `Your system is ready to brew.`

For any of my new clients, I will often create these two aliases for their systems:

- `alias xbandaid="sudo xcode-select --reset" #when permissions might be lacking`
- `alias xfix="sudo ln -s /Library/Developer /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/ && sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/CommandLineTools" #for the fix as described above`

I place these aliases in their bash/zsh profile, which on Catalina is typically either `.zshrc` or `.zprofile` if they use `ZSH`, and `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` if they use `BASH`.

***Disclaimer:** Though I have tried this and it has successfully worked on "BigSur" client machines, I am not promising this will work for you on those installations. The same goes for `MacPorts` and `pkgsrc` also known as `pkgin` put out by the `Joyent Software/NetBSD Samsung Group` folks. **They all worked for my clients and me, but reader discretion is advised.***

Answer (score 0):

I had help from the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52761902/14463751)

You must run `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`
to make Terminal start using command line tools inside Xcode