# VS Code C Error - Invalid Active Developer Path

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, xcrun

`xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`

This is the error I get in VS Code's terminal. There are error squiggles under the "#include <stdio.h>" line.

This is after I upgraded to Mac OS Monterey.

What is the reason for this error and what is the solution?

Comment: You probably need to (re?)install XCode command-line tools. This might help: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/install-xcode-command-line-tools/

Comment: You can try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/64619274/10621865 .

Answer (score 10):

When upgrading your Mac OS, sometimes the code command-line tools stop working. This can be resolved by running this in the terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

If you don't have Xcode installed you should do:

```
xcode-select --install
```

which will install the command-line tools without having Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

The fix, luckily, is pretty straight forward. Install the Xcode toolkit! Even if you had it installed before, you might have to re-register it or update it to the latest version.

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

If that doesn’t work, force it to reset. You’ll need sudo access for this one.

```
$ sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Comment: Thank you! `sudo xcode-select --reset` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

trying to learn python :

I cant install python on my mac ,some error when installing , tried donwloding all version for mac , still same error :https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/

when debuggong in VS Code : manually-specify-an-interpreter

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter

tried to install an interpreter , failed

checked installed version on my mac , only found a path in
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path, problem after zsh update for flutter

this worked out

```
xcode-select --install
```

This helps me fixing