# VS Code Mac OS Monterey Build issues

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

I am new to programming and my university wants me to use an IDE for CS assignments. I am using VS Code, which worked perfectly fine with BigSur but has been giving me this error when I try to build a C++ program with the clang++ compiler with Mac OS Monterey.

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /Users/ma1i/C++_Programs/CS1136_Programs/lesson5part2.cpp -o /Users/ma1i/C++_Programs/CS1136_Programs/lesson5part2
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Comment: try reinstalling the xcode command line tools? or updating xcode if you have that installed

Comment: Ok. I don't have xcode installed , but ill try to reinstall the command line tools.

Comment: Update: I reinstalled the xcode command line tools and restarted my VS Code, and the build was finished successfully. Do I have to reinstall them every time I update my mac to a new OS in the future?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64619274/10621865 . No need to reinstall.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have Xcode rn but when i do i will do this.