# pip install in a mac

Tags: python, macos, nltk

I was trying to install my dependencies of a project I did in a windows. But every time it complains about dependencies of nltk especially regex. I'm trying to do in virtual environment of python 3.7.5.

```
Complete output (17 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.7/regex
copying regex_3/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.7/regex
copying regex_3/regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.7/regex
copying regex_3/_regex_core.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.7/regex
copying regex_3/test_regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.7/regex
running build_ext
building 'regex._regex' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.7/regex_3
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/Users/Rogerio/Documents/Projects/iagreeaidjangoapikey/env/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c regex_3/_regex.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.7/regex_3/_regex.o
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: what command did u run

Comment: @TroyD pip install nltk

Comment: Install the xcode toolkit `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git is not working after macOS Update (xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-pa)

Answer (score 2):

`xcode-select --install`

This will update or install clang on your system try after executing this command.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having problem after the update?
Then your developer path is not set.

If you have XCODE then to setup the path you need to

1. **Go to preference in Xcode**

[image: go to preference in xcode]

2. **Go to Locations tab**

[image: go to locations tab]

3. **Select Command Line Tools version from dropdown**

[image: select command line tools version]