# How do I make Codeblocks work on macOS big sur?

Tags: xcode, macos, codeblocks, macos-big-sur, xquartz

I recently installed Code::Blocks (version 17.12) on my MacBook Pro 2020 which runs on macOS Big Sur, but something is not working and I can't figure out why. I also installed Python Launcher and IDLE and Xcode and XQuartz. Maybe I installed the wrong version? Can anyone help me? Or maybe recommend an alternative that works on macOS? [I print screened the error it shows every time I try to run codeblocks and attached it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W6kW.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with you. I searched on Google and found [this](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-r9cbW1I8ZkaCt6iYDhcXH981n5FJTpV). This was written by Xaviou from the Code::Blocks community. I used revision 12286's CB_20210102_rev12286_macOS-11.1_x64-wx3.1.5.dmg and it worked perfectly on my MacBook running macOS Big Sur 11.1.

Code::Blocks won't work on macOS Catalina and above because Catalina dropped support for 32-bit apps, and Code::Blocks is a 32-bit app. Xaviou rewrote and compiled the code from Code::Block's GitHub repo to make it 64-bit and usable.

Comment: Remember to uninstall and delete any Code::Blocks files you had before installing!

Comment: Thank you! I just installed the version you sent and it works, but it doesn't run my code. This is the error it shows: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library...  I tried installing Xcode but it still doesn't run. Do you know what I have to do?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52522566/15017153
I'm sorry it took so long to reply -- I forgot about this 

Comment: 2 links mentioned above:
https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,24306.0.html
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-r9cbW1I8ZkaCt6iYDhcXH981n5FJTpV

Answer (score 0):

Code Block is not supported to work on BigSur at the moment and the developers need to update it unfortunately.