# Failure to install Jupyter Notebook on MacBook Pro (MacOS) "Failed to build argon2-cffi"

Tags: python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

pip install notebook fails with the following error. I searched for solutions, including Microsoft C++ Build Tools but that only seems to be available for Windows, not Mac, so I can't install/use it.

Extra info:
pip -V: Python 3.6
python3 -V: Python 3.6.2
which python3: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
which pip: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip

Error below:

````
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /var/folders/z0/r17sjj3s3qq1v5wdb9tfn55c0000gn/T/tmpwib2790l
       cwd: /private/var/folders/z0/r17sjj3s3qq1v5wdb9tfn55c0000gn/T/pip-install-2ixbps3p/argon2-cffi_a92129f3f3ed4b99a016674f0933f05e
  Complete output (24 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/argon2
  copying src/argon2/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/argon2
  copying src/argon2/low_level.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/argon2
  copying src/argon2/_ffi_build.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/argon2
  copying src/argon2/_password_hasher.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/argon2
  copying src/argon2/exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/argon2
  copying src/argon2/_legacy.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/argon2
  copying src/argon2/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/argon2
  copying src/argon2/_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/argon2
  running build_clib
  building 'argon2' library
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/extras
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/extras/libargon2
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/extras/libargon2/src
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/extras/libargon2/src/blake2
  /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -msse2 -Iextras/libargon2/src/../include -Iextras/libargon2/src/blake2 -c extras/libargon2/src/argon2.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/extras/libargon2/src/argon2.o
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for argon2-cffi
Failed to build argon2-cffi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for argon2-cffi which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git is not working after macOS Update (xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-pa) (The question is for git, though the solution should be the same for your problem)

Comment: I updated Xcode Command Line Tools and the install is working now!