# Issue installing program on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, error-messaging

I am trying to install a program that I need to use for my research, but I am running into issues. The program is called "hmf," and I can sucessfully install it using `pip install hmf`. However, when I try to import a module, I get an issue: [This image shows the error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmVtY.png), which is

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'CAMB' from 'hmf.density_field.transfer_models' (/Users/cammienorton/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hmf/density_field/transfer_models.py)
```

As per the online suggestion on https://hmf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html I have tried running

```
conda install -c conda-forge numpy scipy astropy camb
```

and I don't get any error messages. Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

UPDATE: I tried `pip install CAMB` and received the [following error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdLbB.png), which says that there was an error while building the wheel.

Comment: Possibly `pip` does not refer to the Python distribution you are using. You can check the version of `pip` and its path using the command `pip --version`

Comment: @gofvonx I checked this, and ensured that I have the most updated version of pip. I still get the same error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CAMB package is not available in you python installation

```
pip install CAMB
```

this should fix

Comment: I tried this, and received another error message, that says an error occurred while building wheel for CAMB (setup.py). Any idea as to what this means?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the whole error message.

Comment: i have a quick question are you using mac? if yes then look at this [stackoverflow question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-pa) if not then maybe this issue on github can help [github issue link](https://github.com/cmbant/CAMB/issues/57)

Comment: I was using mac, and this worked! Thank you so much!