# Can't install visualizeR package in R (part of climate4R packages)

Tags: r, installation, package

I'm working through a jupyter notebook that demonstrates how to use the climate4R package. I've been able to download all the packages except the visualizeR package.

```
devtools::install_github(c("SantanderMetGroup/loadeR@v1.4.14",
                           "SantanderMetGroup/transformeR@v1.5.1",
                           "SantanderMetGroup/downscaleR@v3.1.0",
                           "SantanderMetGroup/visualizeR@v1.4.0",
                           "SantanderMetGroup/VALUE@v2.1.1",
                           "SantanderMetGroup/climate4R.value@v0.0.1"))
```

When I try to download it individually, I get the following error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘visualizeR’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading

    _______   ____  ___________________  __  ________ 
   / ___/ /  / /  |/  / __  /_  __/ __/ / / / / __  / 
  / /  / /  / / /|_/ / /_/ / / / / __/ / /_/ / /_/_/  
 / /__/ /__/ / /  / / __  / / / / /__ /___  / / \ \ 
 \___/____/_/_/  /_/_/ /_/ /_/  \___/    /_/\/   \_\ 
 
      github.com/SantanderMetGroup/climate4R

xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Warning in system2("/usr/bin/otool", c("-L", shQuote(DSO)), stdout = TRUE) :
  running command ''/usr/bin/otool' -L '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/tcltk/libs//tcltk.so'' had status 1
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so
  Reason: image not found
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘visualizeR’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/visualizeR’
Error: Failed to install 'visualizeR' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/var/folders/ym/bpdlwttd35n1gjbfn9ws8yc40000gn/T//RtmpKlQ5pd/filec0b861605783/visualizeR_1.6.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I know that the transformR package is a dependency but I've been able to install that just fine.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you are on a mac. Have you installed xcode? That's required for compiling packages from source (github). You can also try just running `xcode-select --install` in a terminal window. You should restart R after installing xcode.

Comment: I downloaded the Xcode command line tools and tried to set the directory to sudo /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools per this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-pa However this didn't seem to help - do you know what else I can do?