# How to download psycopg2 on Mac OS

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I am trying to get postgresql up and running on my computer to use with python3. From what I understand, I have to download postgresql and then psycopg2. I used the command

```
brew install postgresql
```

which worked without any error. I then proceeded to do

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

but got the error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyscopg2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyscopg2
```

I know that psycopg2-binary exists, but I would rather not install it unless I have to.

EDIT:
Turns out as wu.guan.feng.yue pointed out, I had a typo (fixed now). Unfortunately, I just got another error.

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.9.1.tar.gz (379 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for psycopg2, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/zb/6bvbfsfn6fqdl6wzjp52ykj80000gn/T/pip-install-w901ehls/psycopg2_8dfb1124ccd54b17b1211b191de99482/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/zb/6bvbfsfn6fqdl6wzjp52ykj80000gn/T/pip-install-w901ehls/psycopg2_8dfb1124ccd54b17b1211b191de99482/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/zb/6bvbfsfn6fqdl6wzjp52ykj80000gn/T/pip-record-x11loqj9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/psycopg2
         cwd: /private/var/folders/zb/6bvbfsfn6fqdl6wzjp52ykj80000gn/T/pip-install-w901ehls/psycopg2_8dfb1124ccd54b17b1211b191de99482/
    Complete output (34 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.9.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -I/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/69.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
    xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
    
    It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
    
    You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
    If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
    required for the build and try again.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
    
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/zb/6bvbfsfn6fqdl6wzjp52ykj80000gn/T/pip-install-w901ehls/psycopg2_8dfb1124ccd54b17b1211b191de99482/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/zb/6bvbfsfn6fqdl6wzjp52ykj80000gn/T/pip-install-w901ehls/psycopg2_8dfb1124ccd54b17b1211b191de99482/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/zb/6bvbfsfn6fqdl6wzjp52ykj80000gn/T/pip-record-x11loqj9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have a typo "pscyopg2". Do you mean by `pip3 install psycopg2`?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I just got another error.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the answer. I noticed one line of the error said

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

I looked it up finding this question: [Git is not working after macOS Update (xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-pa).
Turned out the problem was that I needed to run the command

```
xcode-select --install
```

in order to update the Xcode Command-line Tools.