# Trouble installing ibm-db api for python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, db2

I'm failing to pip install the ibm-db connect api.  I'm using jupyter notebook in anaconda. I've tried the following different versions and each time I get the same error message (below).

```
!pip install ibm-db
!pip install ibm_db
!pip install ibm_db_sa
```

Error appears during the install as follows (too long to paste the whole thing so i took the top and bottom error messages).

I'm using macOS Big Sur 11.5.2.

```
Collecting ibm-db
  Using cached ibm_db-3.0.4.tar.gz (796 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: ibm-db
  Building wheel for ibm-db (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Applications/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/km/x_cb0wn5249ddhfzzt066kg40000gn/T/pip-install-ars2dw6i/ibm-db_ab69dcaf33094042bf6e8f35562bd362/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/km/x_cb0wn5249ddhfzzt066kg40000gn/T/pip-install-ars2dw6i/ibm-db_ab69dcaf33094042bf6e8f35562bd362/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/km/x_cb0wn5249ddhfzzt066kg40000gn/T/pip-wheel-gzwtbgz0
       cwd: /private/var/folders/km/x_cb0wn5249ddhfzzt066kg40000gn/T/pip-install-ars2dw6i/ibm-db_ab69dcaf33094042bf6e8f35562bd362/
  Complete output (364 lines):
  Detected 64-bit Python
  running bdist_wheel

[...omissis...]

.....
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/km/x_cb0wn5249ddhfzzt066kg40000gn/T/pip-install-ars2dw6i/ibm-db_ab69dcaf33094042bf6e8f35562bd362/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/km/x_cb0wn5249ddhfzzt066kg40000gn/T/pip-install-ars2dw6i/ibm-db_ab69dcaf33094042bf6e8f35562bd362/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/km/x_cb0wn5249ddhfzzt066kg40000gn/T/pip-record-_5eo3goo/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Applications/anaconda3/include/python3.8/ibm-db Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: When using anaconda, it is best to use the `conda` command to install extensions for python , because that will try to ensure that all dependencies are met. There are known c-library dependency difficulties with macOS  11.x recently, some with workarounds, refer to the issues page for ibm_db module on github and open a ticket there:   https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried and failed with conda install also so went ahead with opening a ticket on github.  I'll post back here with a conclusion. Tx for reply.

Comment: For anyone else searching for a solution here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-pa