# Whenever I try to run g++ in macos monterey it shows invalid active developer path. How to resolve this?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, compiler-errors, macos-monterey

Whenever I try to run g++ in macos monterey it shows invalid active developer path

```
g++ --version
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Comment: Possibly [related](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a) as is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-pa).

Comment: Update xcode or the command line tools

Comment: Probably both just to be safe. They created a much clearer separation with I think Big Sur. If I were picking just one, I'd try the CLT first.

Comment: If you are trying to run *actual* `g++`, you may want to `brew install gcc` which will install 11.2.0.  I presume you are aware of [brew](https://brew.sh/) for macOS.