# Cannot install pyAudio

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

I'm trying to install pyAudio using pip for a Voice Assistant project I'm building. When I try to run the code, it returns this error saying no module named 'pyaudio'. So I assumed I have to install pyaudio again in order to make it work.

But while installing pyaudio, I'm getting this error. I've tried many methods like installing portaudio, clearing cache of pip, updating, uninstalling, re-installing packages, pip and python.

I'm fairy new to python so please don't mind if this is a rookie error.

macOS 12.3.1, Python 3.9.1, env virtual environment

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
      copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DMACOSX=1 -I/Users/setukumar/Downloads/Virtual-Personal-Assistant-using-Python-master/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src/_portaudiomodule.o
      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for pyaudio did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      running install
      /Users/setukumar/Downloads/Virtual-Personal-Assistant-using-Python-master/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
      copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DMACOSX=1 -I/Users/setukumar/Downloads/Virtual-Personal-Assistant-using-Python-master/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src/_portaudiomodule.o
      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pyaudio

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: Please research your inquiry before posting - in the interest of content quality, duplicate questions aren't permitted. This is a duplicate of [Git is not working after macOS Update (xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-pa)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+xcrun%3A+error%3A+invalid+active+developer+path+missing+xcrun

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev
```

Then Try again

Comment: Can you better support your assertion that this particular package is what the OP needs to resolve this error? The error itself is indicative of needing to install Xcode Command Line Tools, not whatever this package is.